# AngularJS send array in $http

Tags: php, angularjs

I've a data like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  list: {name: "foo"},{name: "bar"}
}
```

And send it with AngularJS `$http`:

```
$http({
  method: "GET",
  url: "url",
  params: data
}).then(function(result){
  console.log(result);
});
```

In server it will send like this

```
id: 1
list: {"name": "foo"}
list: {"name": "bar"}
```

And if I `print_r` the value in PHP only the last **list** was received how can I make it an array?

Comment: You should use index braces to make it an array of your list as e.g.: **list: [{name: "foo"},{name: "bar"}]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
  id: 1,
  list: [{name: "foo"},{name: "bar"}]
}
```

Comment: in PHP when I print_r the list it become like this [{\"name\":\"foo\",},{\"name\":\"bar\"}]

Comment: JSON.parse(print_r)